# Cant grant access to any user in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Getting `Access denied for user 'root'@'1-' (using password: YES)` in Java when trying to create MySQL connection.
[image]

You can see that i set all prvileges to any user in mysql. So why then im getting access error ?
There is connection code in Java :

```
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    String ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + ip + ":3306/forum","root","correct_password_there");
```

Comment: You're not granting access to any user as per the lines you attach, you're granting access to root.  What exactly are you trying to access via java? Could you include the error and the connection code in your question?

Comment: also i grant '%'@'%' so there must be 100% access, but no

Comment: Do you use a password to connect to mysql via terminal?

Comment: yes, sure, always

Comment: now im getting access denied for root@localhost in mysql cmd

Comment: Now it makes more sense, however, the issue is clearly not in your java code, but in your mysql config for root

Comment: In your my.cnf, there's a line "bind_address=127.0.0.1".  Comment the line out and restart mysql.